# How to create a Indexed Row Matrix in Scala Spark which is random for given dimensions

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to create an Indexed Row Matrix in Scala - Spark which has random values in the vector. 
I have been able to create a local array using the code below but it messes up for large dimensions -

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.random.RandomRDDs._
import scala.util.Random
var r = scala.util.Random

var populationSize   = 15
var chromosomeLength = 4

var randomPopulation = Array.fill(populationSize,chromosomeLength{r.nextFloat}
```

This should yield something like this

```
 [1, [random vector of length 4]
  2 , [random vector of length 4] ....15 [random vector of length 4] ]
```

which is an Indexed Row Matrix .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plain and simple

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.random.RandomRDDs
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.{IndexedRowMatrix, IndexedRow}

new IndexedRowMatrix(
  RandomRDDs.uniformVectorRDD(sc, populationSize, chromosomeLength)
    .zipWithIndex.map { case (v, i) => IndexedRow(i, v) }
)
```

where `sc` is an instance of `SparkContext` or

Comment: How do you print this ?